# move code to the bottom of a page without effecting it's position on the finished page

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-position

I am working on a website with a very long list of items (around 200), currently displayed in a drop down on the top of a page. For SEO reasons, I'd like to move the code for this to the bottom of the page, so that it can be ignored by the search engines, but I do not want to change the location that the content is displayed on the page when loaded if that makes sense.

Is there an non-javascript way to do this, or even a javascript way of doing it?

Comment: You may benefit from posting your code.

Comment: I didn't think that the code would make much difference as this solution could apply to numerous situations.

Comment: can you use css positioning?

Comment: You can do it with absolute positioning, but it's going to require you to work around it with the other page elements. I wouldn't think it would be worth the hassle. Do you have jQuery available?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like **[this?](http://jsfiddle.net/ilmkamil/Y3ZRv/)**

**html**

```
<div id="contents">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</div>
<div id="top-items">
    <p>Top Items</p>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#top-items {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    background:#333;
    height:40px;
    color:#FFF;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    text-align:center;
}
#contents {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    padding:30px 0 0 0;
}
```